# Is there a way to rotate the background image of a Canvas without rotating the whole canvas? See example

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, chart.js

Its a rough sample but would like to move the needle image as mouse moves without rotating the doughnut chart.  Or is there a better way to approach it?

html:

```
<canvas id="myChart" style="background:url('https://th.bing.com/th/id/R.2db409a16ede3960a7b29d352023f96b?rik=fmfST8altAgOzw&riu=http%3a%2f%2fwww.clker.com%2fcliparts%2fM%2fx%2fk%2f6%2fA%2fw%2fred-compass-needle-hi.png&ehk=lc9ZHlPQDSYqkD9apB6GLPDGgANmGVqnzx05ht2zekw%3d&risl=&pid=ImgRaw&r=0')no-repeat center; background-size:auto 30%; " height="100"></canvas>
```

script:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3],
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)'
      ],
      borderColor: [
        'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)'
      ],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    tooltips: {
      callbacks: {
        title: function(tooltipItem, data) {
          return data['labels'][tooltipItem[0]['index']];
        },
        label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
          return data['datasets'][0]['data'][tooltipItem['index']];
        },
        afterLabel: function(tooltipItem, data) {
          var dataset = data['datasets'][0];
          var percent = Math.round((dataset['data'][tooltipItem['index']] / dataset["_meta"][0]['total']) * 100)
          return '(' + percent + '%)';
        }
      },
      backgroundColor: '#FFF',
      titleFontSize: 16,
      titleFontColor: '#0066ff',
      bodyFontColor: '#000',
      bodyFontSize: 14,
      displayColors: false
    }
  }
});
var img = $('#myChart');
if (img.length > 0) {
    var offset = img.offset();

    function mouse(evt) {
        var center_x = (offset.left) + (img.width() / 2);
        var center_y = (offset.top) + (img.height() / 2);
        var mouse_x = evt.pageX;
        var mouse_y = evt.pageY;
        var radians = Math.atan2(mouse_x - center_x, mouse_y - center_y);
        var degree = (radians * (180 / Math.PI) * -1) + 90;
        img.css('-moz-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
        img.css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
        img.css('-o-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
        img.css('-ms-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
    }
    $(document).mousemove(mouse);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" style="background:url('https://th.bing.com/th/id/R.2db409a16ede3960a7b29d352023f96b?rik=fmfST8altAgOzw&riu=http%3a%2f%2fwww.clker.com%2fcliparts%2fM%2fx%2fk%2f6%2fA%2fw%2fred-compass-needle-hi.png&ehk=lc9ZHlPQDSYqkD9apB6GLPDGgANmGVqnzx05ht2zekw%3d&risl=&pid=ImgRaw&r=0')no-repeat center; background-size:auto 30%; " height="100"></canvas>
```

```
https://jsfiddle.net/wtzj4fhr/
```

Comment: Usual method is to have two canvas elements on top of each other, then you can change one without affecting the other.  In this case, I would recommend *re-drawing* the needle (on its own canvas) rather than rotating the html element, but it probably won't make much difference, depends on what else you do (eg if you add text on the pointer, you don't want that rotated)

Comment: Or adding the needle as an IMG element on top of the canvas and performing rotation with CSS on it.